# Progress tracker with calender

Tags: calendar, productivity, issue-tracker, todo

I need to track my daily tasks. The plan is I'd list my tasks which I plan to do daily for a month and mark each date when I finish a task.

For example, I might have these tasks

- Learn new technology daily (30 mins)
- Try to help Software Recommendation SE daily (30 mins)
- Practice Skill **A** daily  etc

Whenever I complete a task, I'd mark it in the monthly calendar view. After end of the month, I can see which tasks I completed most successfully and if a goal is reached (optional).

http://chaincalendar.com/ seems to be a simple one. But I need to switch to multiple pages for only a task. Also It is convenient to have such tool for Desktop and Mobile.

My computer OS is Ubuntu Linux and I use Android OS in my Mobile.

Is there any such application? I prefer a simple one because complex apps are overkill.

Comment: By the way, many people are rediscovering the analog approach for this, with [bullet-journalling](http://bulletjournal.com) being all the rage now. There is a quiet pleasure to be found in using your [choice of ink](http://noodlersink.com) on [good paper](https://www.rhodiapads.com/collections_dot_everything.php) with a nice pen, perhaps a [basic fountain pen](https://www.gouletpens.com/Pilot-Metropolitan/c/191/?sortBy=productName+asc&facetValueFilter=Tenant~Type%3Afountain_pens) while tracking these personal goals and thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

I found this app [Goal tracker & Habit list](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.intrasoft.habitgoaltracker&hl=en) to be exact thing I wanted. It has calendar view for the tasks and a simple interface and at the end of the month I can view how I did with the task.

This is a screenshot of the app view

[image: app's screenshot]